# SQLAlchemy: Call a method in another class with lazy=dynamic

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How do I call a method in another class in my models? The relationship between Model1 and Model2 is MtM.

```
class Model1(db.Model):
    model2 = db.relationship('Model2', lazy='dynamic')
    # call other_method
 
class Model2(db.Model):
    def other_method(self):
    # method stuff
```

If I'm inside `Model1`, how do I call `other_method` (which is supposed to get the most recent record of `Model2`) knowing I can access the relationship there?

Answer (score 0):

It is quite hard to guess what you are trying to do as the snippet you presented is very limited. Also it is not really clear what exact relationship there is between model1 and model2.

Anyway, I guess you could do something like this (not tested):

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import object_session

class Model1(db.Model):
    model2 = db.relationship('Model2', lazy='dynamic')

    # call other_method
    @property
    def other_method(self):
        return object_session(self).query(Model2).\
               with_parent(self).scalar().other_method()
 
class Model2(db.Model):
    def other_method(self):
    # method stuff
```

Depending on the relationship and the method itself, you might also have to adjust the query further.